# C# equivalent for python code maps and lambda

Tags: c#, python, linq

I was going through Floyd and Warshall algorithm and wanted to convert this python snippet in C# using LINQ

```
def Algorithm(graph):
    '''2-D array which stores the graph value'''
    dist = map(lambda i : map(lambda j : j , i) , graph)
```

Comment: Could you please explain the goal of this method?

Comment: Hint: `map` corresponds to a `Select` in LINQ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sweeper Thanks for the hint.

Here is the code block for the above snippet :

```
public void Algorithm(int[,] graph)
{
    int j;
    var dist = ((int[,])graph).Cast<int>().ToArray().GroupBy(x => j++ / graph.GetLength(1)).Select(y => y.ToArray()).ToArray();
 }
```